# How to solve :Could not find or load main class org.testng.Converter; error in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed java **jdk-14.0.2** and **Eclipse IDE 2020-06**. I've checked java version using `java -version` and java compiler using `javac` in command prompt and everything is fine. I tried to run `System.out.priintln("Hello World");` and I'm getting the following error in console:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.Converter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.Converter
```

What I've tried: I tried uninstalling and re-installing java jdk and eclipse package, but same problem exists.

I'm extremely new to java, so please help me out and if I'm missing something, please let me know.

Comment: Check in eclipse problems section to see if there are any errors in eclipse.Window -> ShowView->Problems

Comment: Thankyou so much @Santoshb , I checked my problems tab and solved it manually and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my list of problems, through Window -> ShowView -> Problems as @Santosh b mentioned above in comment section and the problem was:

```
must declare a named package eclipse because this compilation unit is associated to the named module x
```

and I solved it by deleting the `module-info.java` at my Project Explorer tab.